# C++ to extract data between two strings

Tags: c++, extract, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am looking for a c++ code which can extract some specific content from a file example.txt between two strings and ignore the rest content. for example a file example.txt have below lines

```
xyz
abc
['Content','en']],
<html>hi this is a line <br></html>
',true], 
suzi 20
```

I want to extract code between **['Content','en']],** and **',true],** which means

```
<html>hi this is a line <br></html>
```

Please note that i am not expert in programming and using dev++ compiler

Comment: 1. Dont use dev-c++. 2. Read about `regex`

Comment: looking for a solution for this , can this be done without regex ? if so can you please provide a code

Comment: @AhmedMehtab SO isn't a code writing service; you should post what you've tried and highlight the specific point that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest idea is to read the file into a string, and then extract the content:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string extract(std::string const& tag_begin, std::string const& tag_end, std::istream& input)
{
    // file stream -> in memory string
    std::string filedata((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    // find content start and stop
    auto content_start = filedata.find(tag_begin);
    if (content_start == std::string::npos) {
        return ""; // error handling
    }
    content_start += tag_begin.size();
    auto content_end   = filedata.find(tag_end, content_start);
    auto content_size  = content_end - content_start;

    // extract (copy) content to other string
    auto content = filedata.substr(content_start, content_size);
    return content;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff24e988530d0221)

Then, you'll need to adapt this generic solution to your needs.

Comment: you could create the `content` string from the two iterators directly, no need for `content_size`

Comment: @bolov I would have to get the begin and end iterators from `content_start` and `content_stop` which is comparatively equally annoying to do.

Comment: I thought that `content_start` and `content_stop` are iterators. My mistake.